# Location updates not showing for GPS

Tags: java, android, gps, location, locationmanager

I'm trying to retrieve the device's current location using the device's GPS. When I register for updates (as shown below) for `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` no updates are rolling, yet when I do the same for `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` I get the updates.

I have tested it on my Android device (not the emulator). I have also made sure the GPS is on. Other apps (not mine) are able to access my location. What am I missing here?

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            locationRetrieved(location, this);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { providerDisabled(); }
};

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPS start up is not an instant process. The receiver basically has to know the position of each of the GPS satellites in the constellation in order to calculate it's location

Are you first checking if there is a last known location which you can use? Most apps first check for it and then search for a location.

Comment: I was actually thinking about that, but nothing shows up after an hour. Does it take that long?

Comment: That could be due to under roof try it in open space or check out the same with default map application

Answer (score -1):

You should check wheter your phone is allowing the gathering of location with GPS.

Probabily what is happening is that in Settings -> Location you only have the checkbox for wireless location. If so, the GPS_PROVIDER doesn't work.

Comment: I checked that in a earlier stage using `locationManager.isProviderEnabled(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)` and also manually checking for that. GPS's is on.

Comment: See this example, it is implemented with a service but also works on an activity. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/